# "Will speak more in a minute than he will stand to in a month" - what does this "stand to" mean?

Tags: shakespeare, seventeenth-century-english

In Romeo and Juliet Act 2 Scene 4, Mercutio departs with Benvolio, leaving Romeo to speak with Juliet's nurse, whom Mercutio has mocked and insulted. Nurse asks Romeo who this rude and raucous fellow is, and Romeo replies:

> A gentleman, Nurse, that loves to hear himself talk, and will speak more in a minute than he will stand to in a month.

The "translation" of this on [this SparkNotes page](https://www.sparknotes.com/nofear/shakespeare/romeojuliet/page_118/) says:

> Nurse, he’s a man who likes to hear the sound of his own voice. He says more in one minute than he does in a whole month.

But I am sceptical, as this statement doesn't make sense (though perhaps that's the point).

Anyway, the only part of the original text that is difficult for me to understand is "stand to". What does that phrase mean in the context?

Comment: Perhaps he’s contrasting what he speaks in a minute with what he tolerates (stands to) being spoken to in a month.

Comment: @Lawrence that's my thought as well - it feels like it should mean *tolerates* or *will listen to*, but I haven't found any interpretation that agrees with me yet

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of this "stand to" would be "stand by", hinting at the person talking a lot without caring too much about what is being said. Hence, as the importance is on talking and not following through on what was said, he does not stand by what he has said.

Comment: That also sounds likely